# MySQL: #1060 - Duplicate column name

Tags: mysql

Just wondering why i get this error when I run sql in phpmyadmin

I get this error:

> #1060 - Duplicate column name

when I run this code:

```
ALTER TABLE filters ADD location_dating VARCHAR(100);
ALTER TABLE filters ADD age_range VARCHAR(100);
ALTER TABLE filters ADD distance_range VARCHAR(100);
UPDATE filters SET location_dating='0',age_range='16,100',distance_range='0,500’;
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Probably because you want to add a column that already exists?

Comment: Here you try to add duplicate column name thats why the error.I hope you try to change `column name` of the particular table. right?

for change name of the column using this query

`ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `old_name` `new_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;`

or if you add new column means 

`ALTER TABLE tab_name ADD col_name VARCHAR( 100 )`

Comment: Hi, but is no duplicate table like that please see screenshot here: http://postimg.org/image/3rogaukdn i am confused.

Comment: Sorry guys i found the table in Filters and made the changes manualy in the column, sorry for waisting your time.